# Unstable connecting to wifi router on macos

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, router

I have a problem with wifi on my MacBook Pro. I use the Sierra system. Connecting to stationary routers is very unstable. There are times when it is ok to interrupt after a few minutes, or lose 90% of bandwidth. What is interesting is that when I use my phone as a router everything works stably and well. To make sure:

1. I connected the phone to the wifi router at home - it works ok.
2. I connected my computer to a wifi router at home - it works very unstable.
3. I connected my computer to my phone as a router - it works ok.
4. I connected the computer to the router in my girl's house - it works unstably.
5. I connected my computer to the router at work - it works ok.

I have already tried everything from osx article. Deleting wifi settings, booting into safe mode, SMC and PRAM reset.

I attach screenshots. The first is a connection to wifi router that is unstable and the other is connecting to the phone that works great.

[Wifi Router - unstable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLJIF.png)
[Phone Wifi Router - stable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3ik4.png)

Comment: It's clear from your screen shots that your ASUS router's signal is very low, and it's an old 802.11n device, whereas your Android phone's signal is very high, and it's a modern 802.11ac device. Sounds like you need to upgrade your router to an 802.11ac model with high power transmit amplifiers.

Comment: @Spiff Okay, so macbooks pro have weak wifi module? Becouse my old samsung s6 seems to work really good with this router.

Comment: MacBook Pros have excellent Wi-Fi modules. I guess I'd overlooked your mention of the phone working fine.

Comment: @Spiff Do you have any other suggestion what i may check? I already booked phone consultation with apple support center, but it gonna be monday. Would be nice to solve it faster if possible :D. I checked on one more phone. As a wifi router and as a router client. Same situation. My macbook as client of phone router works perfect. Phone as a client of my unstable wifi router as well. The only problem is on the line between computer and the stationary wifi DSL router.

Answer (score 0):

Neighbors' 2.4G wi-fi networks may interfere with your network.

- If your router supports try to use 5G (best solution).
- If router supports only 2.4G try to change in its settings Wi-Fi channel from 6 (what is in use when your connection is unstable) to 11 (what was in use with your phone).
- Try to test your connection when you closer to the router/ check if there are transmit power settings in your router to make its signal more powerful.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Unfortunately looks like my router doesn't support 5G, so i just moved to canal number 11 as you mentioned. Also i tested how it works once I'm really close, but the problem still is not solved. I forgot to mention that once i connect to the unstable router for the first few moments it works great. Problems start later. I also disabled all external apps.

Comment: In your router settings there is log option. You may try to enable logging and see what happens when connection drops.

Comment: I suppose not router is the problem here, as other devices works fine. Only my macbook has problems. In the logs i don't see anything except updates and restarts which i made today trying to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you get WiFi Explorer and see if other wireless networks are interfering with yours.  Maybe many on the same channel. The app is available on the app store.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is just a channel problem on the router: enter the router settings, select a channel far away from the channel it is on now.